# How to get Payer email Id from PayPay iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, paypal

Im using PayPal iOS SDK, after launching the PayPal Payment Screen. User will enter the PayPal email Id and Password. after successful payment Im getting some response from through PayPal delegate methods but I that response Im unable to collect the email Id (PayPal Id) that I have used to login.

Thank You.

Comment: PayPal not allow u to get the username (email): they only provide the order details of the payment. like transaction type ,and status and orderid....

Answer (score 0):

> No, You can not get user's email address. Paypal can not provide you
>   the personal credentials of any users. It can only provide you the
>   order details.